# Using IMPORT RANGE on google sheets for multiple data sets (including blank cells)

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I want to import data from various google sheets. I am able to do this using the following formula (I realise this is probably a little clunky and could be improved)

```
=QUERY(
{
IMPORTRANGE(Summary!A26,"Challenges!A2:P");
IMPORTRANGE(Summary!A25,"Challenges!A2:P");
IMPORTRANGE(Summary!A27,"Challenges!A2:P");
IMPORTRANGE(Summary!A28,"Challenges!A2:P");
IMPORTRANGE(Summary!A29,"Challenges!A2:P");
IMPORTRANGE(Summary!A30,"Challenges!A2:P");
IMPORTRANGE(Summary!A31,"Challenges!A2:P");
IMPORTRANGE(Summary!A32,"Challenges!A2:P");
IMPORTRANGE(Summary!A33,"Challenges!A2:P");
IMPORTRANGE(Summary!A34,"Challenges!A2:P");
IMPORTRANGE(Summary!A35,"Challenges!A2:P")
},
"select * where Col1 is not null").
```

The range of cells with urls (`Sumary!A25:A35`) are for other users (who are not familiar with the formula) to copy and paste links to their sheets each time they are finished to stop me having to find this data each time. However, if any of these cells are left blank the formula does not work. Is there a way to ignore cell if empty, or `importrange` if filled?

I have tried using the `IF` function with no success

Shortended example of my attempt at using the IF function, returned a formula parse error

```
=QUERY(
{
IF(Summary!A26="","",IMPORTRANGE(Summary!A26,"Challenges!A10");
IF(Summary!A25="","",IMPORTRANGE(Summary!A25, "Challenges!A10")
}, 
"select * where Col1 is not null")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with REDUCE in order not to write again and again the IMPORTRANGE part, and there you can check if that range is empty or not. If it's not empty it will stack the new IMPORTRANGE:

```
=QUERY(REDUCE(INDEX(IFERROR(SEQUENCE(1,16)/0)),Summary!A25:A35,LAMBDA(a,v,
IF(v="",a,{a;IMPORTRANGE(v,"Challenges!A2:P")}))),
"select * where Col1 is not null")
```